# Change color of image using pixel changes in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, bitmap, imageview, pixel

I am trying to change the color of the image in red or any other I wrote the following code but after running my application nothing will happen in my emulator
My Code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int x=0,y=0;
ImageView imViewAndroid,displayimg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imViewAndroid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imViewAndroid);
    displayimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.setimageview);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imViewAndroid.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

    for(int i=0;i<imViewAndroid.getWidth();i++){
        for(int j=0;i<imViewAndroid.getHeight();j++)
        {
             pixel=bitmap.getPixel(i,j);
             bitmap.setPixel(i,j,Color.RED);
            displayimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }
```

And my emulator shows thisb[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXIhL.png)

My focus is to get this reult
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZCT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is by using `ColorFilter`.

```java
ColorFilter overlay = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);
Drawable drawable = imageView.getBackground();
drawable.setColorFilter(overlay);
imageView.setBackground(drawable);
```

Comment: But Dear I didn't use ColorFilter kindly check my code and give suggestions

Comment: @CodingWithHammad Your desired images isn't something that easy to achieve by manipulating pixel by pixel. There are **16,777,216** color variations of 24-bit. Let the system handles that.

Comment: So what will i do kindly Help me